# Condition variables: used only to simulate monitors?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I'm reading "Multithreaded, Parallel, and Distributed Programming" by Gregory Andrews, and in this book the author mentions that he'll show how to use locks "in combination with condition variables to simulate monitors".
I have also heard several times that "mutex lock + condition variable" is a common pattern in programs using Posix threads.

So my question is: are there other common uses of condition variables besides this (using them in combination with locks to simulate monitors"? If so, what would be a simple example of usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A monitor enables two different things:

- mutal exclusion - at most one thread may own the monitor at any given time
- cooperation - the thread owning the monitor can opt to wait until it is awakened by a cooperating thread via a notification sent through the monitor

The Posix threading library separates these two concerns into two different objects:

- mutual exclusion is accomplished using a *mutex*
- cooperation is accomplished using a *condition variable*

It is assumed that the cooperation is with regard to some state shared between threads. This state is expected to be protected by a mutex. Thus, the basic wait operation takes two arguments:

- a condition variable to wait for notification (signaling) on
- the mutex protecting the shared state

When a thread waits on a condition variable using a mutex, the mutex is released and the thread is put to sleep. When the thread awakens, it will reacquire the mutex before continuing.

Signaling (notify one thread) or broadcasting (notify all threads) a condition variable does not require a mutex.

Condition variables are intended solely for this use. It is possible to use them as a "sleep for a while and release this mutex while you sleep" command by using a private condition variable that is never signaled and a timed wait (`pthread_cond_timedwait()`).

Answer (score 2):

A condition variable is always used in conjunction with a mutex. For example, when you call [`pthread_cond_wait`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html), you *must* specify not only the condition variable itself, but also the mutex you're using with it.